# Django rest framework self.get_object() crashes my application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
    @detail_route(methods=['POST', 'DELETE'], permission_classes=[BubbleIsMember])
    @parser_classes((FormParser, MultiPartParser,))
    def rsvp(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = {'message' : 'Error'}
        try:
            post_data = request.data
        except:
            response_data['message'] = 'Malformed json. We received:' + json.dumps(request.data)
            return Response(response_data, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if 'meeting' not in request.data:
            response_data['message'] = "'meeting' field is required"
            return Response(response_data, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            meeting = Meeting.objects.get(pk=post_data['meeting'], bubble=self.get_object())
            print("self", self)
            rsvp, created = MeetingRSVP.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, meeting=meeting)
```

self.get_object() after that line; code doesn't get processed.

Below is what my only 'self' looks like, I'm trying to get bubble object from it.

```
<arrowapi.views.bubble.BubbleViewSet object at 0x1067728d0>
```

My queryset within that View looks like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return Bubble.objects.all()
        elif self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            memberships = BubbleMembership.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values_list('bubble', flat=True)
            return Bubble.objects.filter(pk__in=memberships)
        else:
            return Bubble.objects.none()
```

Comment: it would be better if you add the full code of your view and traceback if any

Comment: Where is `get_object()` in that view? I guess you can use `get_object()` in CBV such as DetailView. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a ModelViewSet here?